# Where to store class files?

Tags: c#, conventions

I usually make a separate class library for my projects and then break it up into folders

```
Services
 -all my .cs files that are service(business logic)

Data
 - Mapping 
   - nhibernate mapping files

Domain
  - domain files
```

I also create other folders like for instance I am doing stuff with foursquare so for all the `class files` for it are in a folder called `"foursquare"`

but what I don't know where to put `one off class files`. Like for instance I have `"HtmlWhiteList" class` what is the only kind of white list.

I don't think it should have it's own folder since it is just one file but at the same time I don't like just having it in the root.

Any suggestions where to put class files that don't deserve their own folder?

Comment: Is the white list used by anything in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, I put new class files just in the root of the other class calling it. If I get 5 or more similar classes, I'll create a folder and put them in the folder on that same level.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I've created a "Utilities" folder that holds other stuff.  Things normally go there and then migrate somewhere else once they have other classes that are similar... but sometimes they stay there.  Certainly this is very subjective to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I would just put it in with the classes of the code that call it. Otherwise just give it its own folder, there's no guarantee that it will always be the only class that belongs there. I think this is more an opinion question than one with a concrete answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

We stopped using this kind of structure. It ended up in having folders like "enums", "interfaces", "entities". When you write code for a feature, lets say the feature "orders", you need all namespaces to get the types you need, because orders-related classes are distributed all over the place. So we changed to a feature oriented structure with namespaces like "orders", "articles", "users" and so on.

There is an advise in the [.Net naming guidelines, Names of Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx):

```
<Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]
```

To which feature belongs the `HtmlWhiteList`? To security? To the client sessions? I can't tell you, because I don't know what it is.

Comment: yeah.. I've even seen a setup that had projects "xxx.yyy.Enums" and "xxx.yyy.Data" that contained only enums and only datastructres from all around the project. Then was a project Commands, and another ViewModels, and so on. Then the MainProject referenced them all and glued the application together. On the other hand - inside those projects, a very clean and logical module-and-featur-wise folder structures were held.. I had really mixed feelings for this.

Comment: Namespaces should be structured the way that an average user of the classes (e.g. a service) requires as less as possible (reduce "usings") and sees only classes that are of interest. IMHO, this is the only relevant criteria for namespaces. Feature-oriented namespaces are pretty good so and easy to understand.

Comment: Um.. I was speaking about Projects/Assemblies and their internal source code Directory structure. I said nothing about namespaces ;) Anyways, I just wanted to confirm the problem you hit with "enums" "interfaces". "Mixed feelings" were related to the fact that the team was fluent with it and the in-project structure was clean, so it had some good-side. Even so, I'd never recommend such "enums" "interfaces" setup. Sadly, many available project templates generate and advertise similar (not exact) layouts - i.e. Prism's module templates.

Comment: I think that the project structure should always reflect the namespaces. There is no silver bullet. If the namespaces work for a certain project, there is no need to change it. I our project, the namespace structure became a real maintenance problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know what it does or who uses it and therefore you dont know where to put it, or the thing it does is trivial so it does not deserve having a place, then remove it completely.

If you do not think it is deemed to be removed, then it deserves a place.

If it is used scarcely, then you should exactly know who uses it and what is it's impact on them - then you should instantly know where to put it: somewhere near them.

If there is no such place, create it and live with it. As the project grows, when a better place gets materialized, you can always move it there. Looking at your project structure, if it is true utility, then Service is for not for "BusinessLogic", but for Services and Utilities. If yo umodel your BL as a "service", then that's your choice, but that does not mean the all services are BL.

If there are so many scattered users of this class so that you cannot decide who is more important or more relevant, then create it as a new module/library/folder since it is heavily used and in fact important.